# I need help solving this logarithmic equation $\ln\sqrt{+1}=7$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Here is my work so far.
$$\ln\sqrt{x+1}= e^7$$

$$(x+1)^{1/2}=e^{e^7}$$

Comment: Note that $e^{(e^7)}$ is a number. Just like any number, like $10$. How would you solve
$$
x^{1/2} = 10
$$?

Comment: The title and the body have different equations. Also is it $\ln(\sqrt{x}+1)$ or $\ln(\sqrt{x})+1$?

Comment: gnatgnat2019 :what is your question  $ln\sqrt{x+1}=7$ or $ln\sqrt{x+1}=e^7$

Comment: @LionHeart it is the first equation you mentioned. Sorry I do not know how to format it correctly on here. But yes, the first one you stated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first step would be to remove the natural log on both sides. You do this by:
$$e^{\ln(\sqrt{x+1})}=e^7$$

Remember that $e^{\ln}$ crosses out by the inverse property of logarithms, so you should have
$$\sqrt{x+1}=e^7$$

Next, square both sides to remove the square root:
$$x+1=e^{14}$$

Then solve for x equals
$$x=e^{14}-1$$

Comment: Thank you for your help, I understood now.

Answer (score 1):

$b=lna=log{_e}^a$, then, $a=e^b$, where a is a positive real number.

$\ln\sqrt{+1}=7$

$\sqrt{+1}=e^7$

$x+1=(e^7)^2$

$x=e^{14}-1$

Comment: Please incorporate text into your answers, so they are not entirely symbolic.  Why the first implication?  Why the second?  Why the third?  And which implications are actually biconditionals?   Don't be sloppy with $\implies$.

Comment: Thank you for your help.